# how to trigger ActiveRecord callbacks (has_paper_trail) for update_all in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i update all the authors
papertrail won't create record in version table b'coz update_all wan't trigger ActiveRecord callbacks

```
Billing.update_all( "author = 'David'", "title LIKE '%Rails%'" )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update all when you need callbacks fired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931812/how-to-update-all-when-you-need-callbacks-fired)

Answer (score 3):

ActiveRecord update_all does not instantiate the objects and does not trigger callbacks. As of version 6.0.2 Airblade still will not insert new versions in the versions table when using `update_all` or batch updates. See issue [#337](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/337)

If you're dealing with a small amount of data at a time, you can trigger callbacks by calling `update` on the relation in Rails 5 [docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11898).

```
Billing.where("title LIKE '%Rails%'").update(author: 'David')
```

If you're using a previous version of Rails, you'll need to loop through the collection of objects and call update on each instance.

Comment: Didn't know this exists in Rails 5.