# update collection with exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to change the status of few records in a database in the transaction, so I need to throw an exception when the error occurs. 
Code below is simplified but shows the problem

```
 User.products.update(status: :vip) # it update but of  didn't throw exception
```

Following [update documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes-21) i tried `update!` method but it does not work

```
  User.products.update!(status: :vip) 
  # NoMethodError: undefined method `update!' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000005463b60
```

How to use `update!` method  with collection? Should I iterate over all records, and call update! on each record?

Comment: As per the [doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class), `update` should check for validations. Also, for callbacks, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931812/how-to-update-all-when-you-need-callbacks-fired) post

Comment: try using update_all

Comment: @Sajin update_all does it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. I need validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not update all records within one query and run validations at the same time. You need to iterate over all records and run `update!` for each of them:

`Product.transaction { User.products.each { |pr| pr.update!(status: :vip) } }`

Comment: What do you mean one query? Do you mean transaction produce one query to the database, and it is a problem?  `update` without `!` run validations on updated records., and produce 2 queries for each record. I want to do the same but with an exception.  Code that you suggest will do the job, but it doesn't answer directly. If nobody put better answer I will mark it as answer.

Comment: You have tried to call `update!` on the collection, that was a problem. Update on the collection can't run record validations, so you need to call `update!` for each record. For collection you can only run `update_all` or `update`, but they do not run validations, they execute one SQL query.

Comment: For collection, you can run both update and update_all. It is not just alias. There are completely different methods. `update` load object and run validations and callback on it but update_all do not.

Comment: Yep. You are right. Take a look at the [rails sources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0e8d4edd56f44b27f33bd214aa03af60cc5d39ae/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L409), you will see that `update` called there.